# Searching for the same string after changing tabs

Tags: firefox, search, user-interface

I am using Mozilla Firefox 32.0.

In most cases when I search for a specific string on a page and do not get any satisfying matches I switch to another open tab and search for the same string there. I have to enter the string each time (or use the clipboard).

Is there any possibility to carry over the search string between tabs so that simply pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> shows me if there are any matches without having to reenter my search?

I would be fine with changes in the settings as well as with an extension that does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the Firefox extension called FindBar Tweak.

It is located here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/

Enjoy!